# Magento 2 setting base image on all store views via REST API does not change base image for specific store on production mode

Tags: magento2, product-images, rest-api

I have a magento 2.2.6 installation with 2 store views, i am setting the base image via the REST API using the `/rest/all/V1/` endpoint.

In developer mode changing the base image updates the base image on both the 'All store views' and the specific storeviews, but in production mode the update only works in 'All store views', and the specific store views still have the old base image.

Could this be a Magento issue or am I misunderstanding the `all` storeview? The only way I can successfully update the base image on all store views right now is by separately calling the API once for each store code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Wouldn't exepect an answer or any help here though.

Comment: Any updates on this one?